# IBM Websphere Studio Application Developer Installation Error

Tags: websphere

I am getting the following error while installing the IBMWebsphere Studio Application Developer 5.1.2 in WinXP Pro.

" The installation of WebSphere Studio cannot continue because the following required parts are missing from the electronic images. Download the required parts and run the installation program again.

C571ILML.bin "

I am installing from the local hdd (d:/temp/disk1, disk2,disk3 and disk4) of setup program.

Can any body help me what could be the problem and how to solve this to install the IBM WAS.

Answer (score 0):

Two questions.

1. Does that file exist anywhere in your install tree?
2. Check it again please, most codes are only 7 characters. The closest I've found is C57I1ML but that's part of Websphere Studio Site Developer 5.1.2. And, on top of that, WSAD 5.1.2 seems to have the C80 prefix.

BTW, there's no C571ILML **anywhere** on the IBM intranet that I can see.

EDIT:

The standard Websphere Studio Application Developer 5.1.2 for Windows has **five** disk images located on IBM's Xtreme Leverage site, those being C802XML, C802YML, C802ZML, C8030ML and C804UML.

I suspect your missing file is due to the fact that you only have the contents of four of those disk images.

You'll need to go back to your source and get the other disk image (or contents).

Alternatively, you may have the Integration Edition, in which case I'll need to look again - please clarify which one you have.